# Recover GPT partitions or partition table

Tags: partitioning, gparted, gpt

I was partitioning a GPT hard disk using Gparted.
I have deleted the Windows recovery partition successfully and merged that unallocated space to another unallocated space which was previously partition D: after I intended to merge the whole unallocated space to partition C:.

When I applied those settings, there was an error I don't remember it actually but it was asking  abort or cancel and I cancelled. But after I rebooted the computer, there is nothing showing on the HDD but unallocated space. Please help about that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo parted -l` or a screenshot of GParted. As it stands, we don't know nearly enough to asses the situation.

Comment: The output is. ATA Toshiba (SCSI). Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB. Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096B. Partition table: GPT. Disk flags:

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [gpart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpart) tool while running on an Ubuntu Live CD:

```
sudo apt-get install gpart
```

This tool scans the disk to find deleted partitions.

A full tutorial is available [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370121).

Comment: I'll try this and I'll tell you what happened. I'm worried that partition that I've deleted was extended therefore every partition next to it was deleted too. I'll update for more details but I'm outside now thanks.

Comment: I attempt to rescue partition table in device option in GParted but it takes a lot of time now the current message is: Searching for file systems on /dev/sda  .

Comment: Just wait until it is finished.

Comment: Unfortunately after mostly 4 hours of scanning no file system found on the mentioned disk.

Comment: did you run gpart or gparted?

Comment: Gparted from live CD

Comment: Try gpart like I wrote in the answer

Comment: Unfortunately nothing found but empty partitions using GPart.

Comment: It's in the universe repository, so you may have to enable that repository first as it's not enabled by default.

Comment: @mdd Gparted Device > ["Attempting data rescue"](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-attempt-data-rescue) uses `gpart`. Documentation say will only recover up to 4 partitions. [Suggest](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-recover-partition-table) [**TestDisk**](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) for a more in-deep scan.