# All hard disk as Unallocated

Tags: partitioning, unallocated

I had Win10 installed on my hard disk and I was trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside W10. During the partition creation I did a mistake and now I have all my disk as Unallocated.

I can't even go inside the W10. This happened while I was creating the partitions for Ubuntu. I am using Live CD / Gparted to do that. It was not working then I tried to create a partition table as MSDOS and I got all the disk as Unallocated.

This is the output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004e2c7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Is there a way to revert this situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You destroyed your disk's partition table. Unless you perform any further writing operations, your data should still be intact. Here are some links for further reading about how to recover partition tables: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery / http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126755/103151 / http://askubuntu.com/q/705037/367990

Comment: I am currently running the testdisk and now I need to choose the partition table type. Which one should I choose?

I have Intel,  EFI GPT, Humax, Mac, None, Sun and Xbox.

thanks

Comment: That depends on what you had before, I think GPT but that's just a guess. To be sure, make a full clone or raw disk image of your disk before performing any rescue attempts, so that you don't destroy more accidentally.

Comment: I don't know how to do that to be honest. Can you explain me briefly please? Thanks